# Why does pip give an error while installing a tool?

Tags: sudo, 19.10, python3, pip, curl

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pip-install-kbqd70bu/pycurl/setup.py", line 234, in configure_unix
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config': 'curl-config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-kbqd70bu/pycurl/setup.py", line 961, in <module>
    ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-kbqd70bu/pycurl/setup.py", line 623, in get_extension
    ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-kbqd70bu/pycurl/setup.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.configure()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-kbqd70bu/pycurl/setup.py", line 238, in configure_unix
    raise ConfigurationError(msg)
__main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config': 'curl-config'
```

Answer (score 0):

It tell you that it can not run `curl-config`

That means usually you are missing one package .

So you can use this website  https://packages.ubuntu.com/

and search for curl-config at the end of path

You must have a result similar to this

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=eoan&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=curl-config

for the second error you are missing a C compiler .

so you need to install `build-essential`

Comment: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-d0902j0p/pycurl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-12zx21pn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-d0902j0p/pycurl/

Comment: i installed the packages it gives this error now

Comment: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.5" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_OPENSSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/docstrings.o
    unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Failed building wheel for pycurl
  Running setup.py clean for pycurl
Failed to build pycurl
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, pycurl, wfuzz
  Running setup.py install for pycurl ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import